# EditText onFocus doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an EditText which I adjust the position on screen of when the user clicks it (when it gains focus). However, the method is not working properly. My code:

```
etHashtag.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                Log.d("EditText", "has focus");
                originalHashtagPos = etHashtag.getY();
                etHashtag.setY(targetH / 2);
            }else {
                Log.d("EditText", "no focus");
                etHashtag.setY(originalHashtagPos);
            }
        }
    });
```

The log shows that the focus is gained when the user clicks the EditText, and it loses focus when the user clicks outside the view. However, the Y position is not moved everytime. It only works in about 50% of the times. Thought this would be simple?

Comment: any screenshots available to illustrate your problem?

Comment: When I click the view, it logs that is has focus, and sometimes it sets the height to targetH / 2 which is half the screen height. Sometimes it does not. So my issue is that it onoy works sometimes.

Comment: Try adding android:focusable="true" to EditText

Comment: The listener is a focus listener and it logs that it has focus every time.